# Azure upload large files with php

Tags: php, azure, web-config

im using Azuer web app, and im trying to upload large files using php code normal php code , so if i upload small files like 12 MB it will upload successfully but if i try larger the result is  "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

So edit php.ini

```
display_errors=On
memory_limit = 5920M
upload_max_filesize= 5120M
post_max_size =5220M
max_input_time = 6000000
max_execution_time = 600000000
```

also .user.ini

```
; Example Settings
display_errors=On
memory_limit = 5920M
upload_max_filesize= 5120M
post_max_size =5220M
max_input_time = 6000000
max_execution_time = 600000000
```

and web.config

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="99999999" maxRequestLength="2000000000" />
```

also i enable the file extentions that i need in web.config

the result is the same message , so please i need a help.

Comment: setting these 3 `memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size`  should be enough to increase upload size.  I'd be really careful setting this `max_execution_time, max_input_time`  globally, if you need to increase it I would do it at run time using `set_time_limit`  None of that will fix your problem though.

Comment: i tried as much i can to do all the solutions in the web  and stackoverflow, but nothing fix it, is it related to azure web app issue or its a normal issue ?

Comment: Could it be possible you have some automated script that deletes files after a certain amount of time?  I would check that the file exists at all.  Googling that error sounds like a 404 response. `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable`  Perhaps you have rewrite rules in .htaccess that are causing issues.

Comment: I used your configuration settings, and successfully uploaded a 27M size file to my Azure test web app server. According your error message, it seems there may be anything wrong with your PHP script. Could you please provide your key code snippet?

Comment: It's always better to upload chunk by chunk of 4mb size.

Comment: i tried other instance of web app , and same problem , im stuck my php code work on localhost but not at azure webapp

Answer (score 0):

In my case besides adding php settings to .user.ini I also had to update IIS web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Description:
You observed 413 HTTP status code from your App Service
So, you would like to increase the upload file size
of the App Service. Please feel free to correct me if I have any
misunderstandings.

Issue Analysis:
I have made some tests on my end, and you could refer to my steps on
increasing the upload file size of my App Service:

```
 * Go to the SSH console of the App Service

    * Go to `site/wwwroot folder`. We will use the command_ echo "<?php
phpinfo();">>info.php_ to create a PHP info page. You could skip this
step if you already have one.

    * Navigate to https://<sitename>.azurewebsites.net/info.php [1], and we
could see the max upload file size is 2M

    * Now we could go back to SSH console and go back to home/site
directory. Use command _mkdir ini_ to create a folder. Go to the folder
and use command _echo "upload_max_filesize=50M" >> extensions.ini_. This
will create a file and write to it. Use command _cat extensions.ini_ and
confirmed the write operation is successful. In this way, we created a
setting and configured the max file upload size to 50M.

    * We’ll now need to go to the Azure Portal and add an Application
Setting to scan the “ini” directory that we just created to apply
the change for upload_max_filesize. In order to do that, you could
navigate to the _configuration_ blade of your App Service and add a new
application setting. For the App Setting Name, enter
_“PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR_”. For the value, enter
“_/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini_”. Please note that
saving application setting change will restart your App Service.

    * Navigate to https://<sitename>.azurewebsites.net/info.php [1], and we
could see the max upload file size has increase to 50M.

    * Remove the info.php page once you’re done using the page.
```

Action Plan:
Based on my testing, I have successfully increased the max upload file
size to 50M. Therefore, may I ask if you could try increasing the max
upload file size and see if this helps on solving the issue?